# Oracle 11c DB Connection Timeout

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

I have a simple test console app where I am trying to connect to Oracle DB via EF 6 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess but each time it says connection timeout. I have tried to increase the timeout period but still no luck, at the end it says connection timeout.

I have purposefully given a false user password, and it still says connection timeout. I have prepared my connection string with this [URL Help](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/), Forth one to be specific.

Following is my main code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var db = new OracleTestContext())
    {
        var users = db.user_tables;
        var firstUser = users.First();
    }
}
```

Following is the error stack

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Connection request timed out
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
  StackTrace:
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at OracleBlog.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 77

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    OracleBlog.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

I don't have `service name`, but I do have the following information on connection string
`SID`, `Host`, `Port`, `User Id`, `Password`

With this information I tried connecting with the SQL Developer client and the connection was successfully established.

Comment: well can you connect to the database outside of c#?

Comment: Yes, I tested with SQL Developer and it was working 
@OldProgrammer

Comment: According to NuGet package [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework): _This NuGet package is for ODP.NET, Managed Driver applications that use Code First and/or Entity Framework 6 applications. It will add the Oracle Entity Framework assembly and auto-configure for its use. Note that this package does not include ODP.NET, Managed Driver which is available as a separate NuGet package._

Comment: Also see: [Oracle .NET Providers on NuGet Gallery](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/net-downloads.html) and [Oracle .NET Developer Center](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet.html)

Comment: I got hold of the serviceName attribute from DBA's and after adding that in the connection string it worked